# File.open works when getting an argument at runtime, but not when getting an argument from the command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, io, argv

If I enter a file name without passing it in the command line (E.g. ARGV would be empty) everything works fine, but if I pass it an argument in the command line I always get a File or directory does not exist exception.

E.g. file.rb test.txt will except everything.

```
start_dir = "file-io-samples/junk/"

begin
  if ARGV.empty?
    print "Enter a file name: "
    file_name = start_dir + gets.chomp
  else
    file_name = start_dir + ARGV[0].chomp
    puts "Writing to #{file_name}..."
  end
  fail "File Exists" if File.exist? file_name
  puts "File ready: " if file = File.open(file_name, 'w')
  while line = gets
    break if line.chomp == "!"
    file.puts line
    puts "Written"
  end
rescue Exception
  puts "Exception Raised: #{$!}"
ensure
  puts file.close
end
```

Comment: What are you actually passing on the command line, what are you actually inputting when prompted, and can you post the error message?

Comment: Ruby file.rb text.txt Error is: Exception Raised (caught by my rescue) File or directory doesnt exist. Which shouldnt happen as it opens with 'w'

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but if you are passing in an absolute path and it works, but a relative path in the code doesn't, you may need to add Rails.root to the file path.

You can join sections of path together like so:

```
file_name = Rails.root.join(start_dir, ARGV[0].chomp)
```